# What does it mean to create a Let's Encrypt certificate "automatically" rather than manually?

Tags: tls, certificates, letsencrypt

I am getting the error below in trying to renew my certificate from the command line (and thus too from cron). From searching similar error reports, I understand  that it means that I initially created a certificate manually and so cannot renew automatically. I am not sure what "manually" means in this context.

(I am not using Nginx integration or the like. Rather, I am running a Nodejs app which references the  SSL certificate files in application code, loading an HTTPS listener alongside the HTTP listener. That works fine.)

What is the way to create certificate that I *can* renew automatically?

```
sudo certbot renew
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Processing /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/shpil.joshuafox.com.conf
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Failed to renew certificate abc.example.com with error: The manual plugin is not working; there may be problems with your existing configuration.
The error was: PluginError('An authentication script must be provided with --manual-auth-hook when using the manual plugin non-interactively.')

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
All renewals failed. The following certificates could not be renewed:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/abc.example.com/fullchain.pem (failure)
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
1 renew failure(s), 0 parse failure(s)
```

Comment: Did that script happen to use DNS hooking?

Comment: I have not set up any special hook. What is DNS hooking? Is it a process for automatically changing DNS zone records to prove ownership of a domain (as I did, manually). Is it what is described here? https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-acquire-a-let-s-encrypt-certificate-using-dns-validation-with-acme-dns-certbot-on-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question title and body ask two different questions. One asks "What does it mean for a certificate to be generated automatically?" and the other is "Why is my script not working?". I will attempt to answer both:

#### What does it mean to create a certificate "automatically"?

In order for a certificate authority to generate a certificate for a domain, they need to verify that the person, who requested the certificate, actually owned the domain. If they did not, you could request a certificate for `security.stackexchange.com`, and I am *fairly* confident that you don't own that domain.

Back in the day, when certificates cost an arm and a leg, that process was quite complicated. But with Let's Encrypt, there are are several different [challenge types](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/), but the two most popular are "HTTP-01" and "DNS-01".

With the HTTP-01 challenge, Let's Encrypt gives you a token, and then expects to find that token under `http://<YOUR_DOMAIN>/.well-known/acme-challenge/<TOKEN>`. Essentially, the idea here is that if you can prove that you can generate valid HTTP responses for that domain, you most likely control that domain.

With the DNS-01 challenge, Let's Encrypt gives you a token, and then expects to find a DNS TXT record under `_acme-challenge.<YOUR_DOMAIN>`, which contains said token. Again, the idea is that if you can publish valid DNS records for a domain, you most likely own that domain.

Armed with that knowledge, we can now look at automation. It's easy to do all of this manually, and for a long time, that's precisely what I did, four times a year. I'd issue a certificate request, go to my DNS console, add the request, wait for the DNS records to propagate and then confirm that the records can now be checked.

This process is long, tedious and involves a lot of cursing, possibly even a prayer or two to the Omnissiah. Automation would be a lot better! So, let's check what we need to automate:

We need some way to automatically check if our certificate is about to expire, and if so, request a new certificate, a new token, then automatically "deploy" that token and confirm to Let's Encrypt that they can now check the token. If the verification succeeded, we then need to overwrite the old certificate with the new one and possibly instruct the web server to reload the new certificate.

So to answer your first question: **A certificate is considered to be generated "automatically" if it is done via some process, that does not require human intervention in any way.**

#### Why does my script not work?

When you request a new certificate using `certbot`, you have several options:

```
(default) run   Obtain & install a certificate in your current webserver
certonly        Obtain or renew a certificate, but do not install it
renew           Renew all previously obtained certificates that are near expiry
enhance         Add security enhancements to your existing configuration
```

The two most important for generating a certificate is `run` and `certonly`, but for automation, it's `renew`. `run` is used when you trust Apache and nginx integration, `certonly` is when you use a different web server or have problems with the automatic integration.

Aside from the mode, there are also flags, which are where your issue stems from:

```
--apache          Use the Apache plugin for authentication & installation
--standalone      Run a standalone webserver for authentication
--nginx           Use the Nginx plugin for authentication & installation
--webroot         Place files in a server's webroot folder for authentication
--manual          Obtain certificates interactively, or using shell script hooks
```

The first four are all for the "HTTP-01" kind of challenge. Essentially, they try to figure out where to place the token, so that your web server will serve the token as requested. `--manual` on the other hand, as the documentation suggests, is when you do things...well...manually. Or if you write your own shell scripts to deal with that.

This is required for DNS challenges, since `certbot` does not include any functionality to automatically enter or modify DNS entries. You first created your certificate using the `--manual` flag, indicating that you would manually create the DNS entries and inform certbot when it's done.

In order to automate this process, the error message explains exactly what you need to do:

> An authentication script must be provided with `--manual-auth-hook` when using the manual plugin non-interactively.

Essentially, you have to specify a script, which will deploy the DNS records for you - if your DNS provider supports that, that is. [This thread](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/dns-providers-who-easily-integrate-with-lets-encrypt-dns-validation/86438) in the Let's Encrypt forums lists DNS providers, for which integration is easy, and even attach several shell scripts, which can do this process for you.

If your DNS provider is *not* listed, you have the following options:

- Switch to HTTP-01 challenges, if possible.
- Write your own shell script, if possible.
- Continue with manual renewal.

I personally switched from DNS-01 to HTTP-01, using the `--standalone` mode, as direct nginx integration gave me issues for servers, which were configured to not be accessible outside `192.168.0.0/24`.

The following lines in my renewal config specify that I want to use standalone mode and automatically shut down nginx before beginning the process, and starting it again after it is done.

```
authenticator = standalone
pre_hook = systemctl stop nginx.service
post_hook = systemctl start nginx.service
```

Comment: I see. So using HTTP-01 seems easier -- and the Nginx plugin will run Nginx on some port other than 80/443, separately from my Nodejs app, to do HTTP-01

Comment: @JoshuaFox I find it easier to stop whichever server is listening on port 80, use the `--standalone` mode and then start it again. You can use the `--dry-run` flag for testing purposes.

Comment: That means killing the production server for as long as this takes, right?

Comment: @JoshuaFox For roughly 20 seconds every two months. If this is an issue, you may need to work on alternatives, such as the `--webroot` flag

Comment: Are there  any reasons *not* to do `--webroot` It seems very easy: No need to stop the server or to run a separate server, no need to work with DNS APIs.

Comment: @JoshuaFox Your server may not have a webroot and work purely as a reverse proxy. That's one instance where `--webroot` would not work.

Comment: Thank you. The `--webroot` approach worked like a charm. Now I need to come back in 2 months and get that it autorenews!

Comment: @JoshuaFox You should be able to set up a cron job. In fact, you should try `sudo certbot renew --dry-run` and see if that gives you a success message. Depending on your distro, certbot may already come with a pre-configured crontab in `/etc/cron.d/certbot`

Comment: Thank you!  The certbot  set up the cron; I edited the cron  and  ran the dry-run. So I am hopeful.

Comment: @JoshuaFox What did you edit in the crontab?

Comment: (1) Reboot the server at the end, so that Nodejs will pick up the new cert. (Maybe I could install `killall node` and rerun the Nodejs server instead of server restart.) (2) Adjusted the schedule to be only monthly to minimize the downtime from (1). Actually, I would want to restart the server only when there has been an actual  renewal of the cert, but I am not sure if there is a simple way to do that.

Comment: @JoshuaFox Oh no, that's not at all how you do that! The crontab was fine as it is. `certbot renew` first checks if the cert is about to expire, and if not, nothing happens. No need to shut down your server. In the certbot renewal config, you can set a pre-auth hook and post-auth hook, which is where you want to stop and restart nodejs. The way you do it now may leave you without a cert for up to a month in the worst case

Comment: Thank you. OK, I'll look into making a post-auth hook

Comment: @JoshuaFox It's in the renewal config. i posted an example of it in my answer. The hook can (and likely should) be as simple as `systemctl stop nodejs`

Comment: Thank you. I believe that a deploy-hook is the right one in contrast to the post_hook that you mentioned. Per the [docs](https://eff-certbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using.html):   "If you want your hook to run only after a successful renewal, use --deploy-hook"  and "--post-hook hooks run before and after each attempt to renew [the cert]." Since I have a simple process rather than a  service, it looks like I need this `certbot renew -q --deployhook "killall node && cd /home/user/node && ./run_server.sh"`

Comment: @JoshuaFox You don't need any of that in the crontab. The crontab was fine as-is. Those things should go into your renewal configs in `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal`